# Xcode project build canceled

Tags: swift2, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode7.3

I have a project that I have been using to learn Xcode/swift/IOS programming. For some time I have testing it  in the simulators as well as on my iPhone 5. Now, all of a sudden it is not possible to install on my iPhone. The reaches "Copying standard swift libraries" and then: "Build canceled". No further information whatsoever. Still runs fine in the simulator. I am using Xcode 7.3/swift 2.2 and IOS 9.3. Also using the Xcode 7 free ad-hoc provisioning.

Comment: Update. I have tried to archive the product with the same result.

Comment: Update. Problem solved by creating a new project and copying all the files. Someone else obviously had the same problem a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by disconnecting the iOS device that was attached during the archiving.